# Tags or function in netbeans ? What are they and how to use them?

Tags: html, netbeans

When I make html files i often get suggestion for tags like this

```
<naturalnumbers>
<notsubset>
```

Netbeans (v 7.4) shows them with icon {} instead of <>.

What is the purpose of these tags ? Where can I find info about them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The {} are from MathML (see [here](http://www.w3.org/Math/)) and some others from SVG (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/intro.html))